# Invalid span tag. Expected closing br tag

Tags: itext

I am trying to convert html to pdf using iText and getting below error.

**Invalid span tag. Expected closing br tag**

How is this an invalid xhtml ?

```
<span style="font-size: 10pt; line-height: 14.2667px;"><br/></span>
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the above, at least as HTML.  Are you sure that the error isn't somewhere else, and perhaps the above is being flagged as a side effect?

Comment: I don't think you can put `br` inside a `span`, since it's a breaking element. `span`s are inline, and must contain only other inline elements.

Comment: *"using iText"* - how exactly? There historically are three different approaches to this, one completely deprecated due to its limitations (`HtmlWorker`), one better but still limited and now in maintenance mode (`XmlWorker`) and one fairly good and still being improved (`pdfHtml`)

Comment: @mkl I am using XMLWorkerHelper.

Comment: You asked the same question twice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52812243/html-parsing-exceptions-in-itext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A span is an inline element, and a smallest element of xhtml tree. 
styling tags like `<u>, <i>, <strong>` can be reside there.

A `<br>` or a `<hr>` is a full width element. Hence it is suggested to use `<br>` inside a `<div></div>`